# How do we pronounce this symbol: $\nabla \phi$

Tags: notation, terminology, pronunciation

I would like to know how to pronounce in English this symbol: $\nabla \phi$.

It is something `phi`  ... ?

Comment: [del](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) phi?

Comment: If you know the context, you can also say "grad phi" (if in the context of gradient), or it could be used in the context of curl or divergence. That's a more "informed" pronunciation that tells you more than just plain notation.

Comment: Thanks to @Daniel, now I know what to call oracles in the future!

Comment: Detexify can sometimes help with this kind of question: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Phira What an awesome site! That should be stickied somewhere (and probably is already)

Comment: @Mathias711 It used to be one of the community ads, I do not know if it is now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inversed delta is called Nabla. So Nabla phi. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol

Comment: Welcome, good question!

Comment: Is it also called nabla when dealing with [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)? I have always called it "nabla" in vector analysis, but I have a doubt for other uses.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: *nabla* is a name of “∇” symbol (cf. *equals sign* – “=”, *times sign* – “×”). *Del* is a name of the operator in vector analysis. The thing with finite differences is not *del,* but if the symbol is “∇”, then it’s *nabla.*

Comment: @IncnisMrsi This makes sense. In physics, though, we always spelled it "nabla phi", not "del phi", but it may be a french usage. Thank you anyway.

Comment: FWIW, "nabla" is an ancient Hebrew word for "harp" or "lyre".  Also, if you google it while at work, google may decide that you meant "NAMBLA" and then your boss will want to talk to you.

Answer (score 3):

it's actually del operator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del
so it is del phi, in mathematics.
nabla article points to that for mathematical usage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol